# SQL query to find available rooms from date x to date y

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following relational schema, how can I derive the available "Basic" types of rooms which are not booked from a DATE RANGE. This is my shot. I am working with oracle in sqlplus

```
SELECT * 
    FROM ROOM r, BOOKING b
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM BOOKINGROOM br
         WHERE br.ROOMNO = r.ROOMNO 
         AND   br.BOOKINGID = b.BOOKINGID
         AND ARRIVEDATE < '01-FEB-2013'
         AND DEPARTDATE > '23-FEB-2013');
```

I also want the query to be 'canned query' so I manually add the end range and start range dates. Sub query answer would be preferred.

```
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES (2314, 1001, TO_DATE('10-MAR-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('15-MAR-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1225.00);
```

Date comparison has been an issue perhaps in the below answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.* 
FROM Room r
LEFT JOIN BookingRoom br ON r.FloorNo = br.FloorNo AND r.RoomNo = br.RoomNo
LEFT JOIN Booking b ON br.BookingId = b.BookingId 
      AND (b.ArriveDate <= &end_range AND b.DepartDate >= &start_range)
WHERE b.BookingId IS NULL
  AND r.Type = 'BASIC';
```

If you absolutely must use a subquery, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.* 
FROM Room r
LEFT JOIN BookingRoom br ON r.FloorNo = br.FloorNo AND r.RoomNo = br.RoomNo
LEFT JOIN Booking b ON br.BookingId = b.BookingId 
WHERE (b.BookingId IS NULL OR b.BookingId NOT IN (
      SELECT BookingId 
      FROM Booking
      WHERE (ArriveDate <= &end_range AND DepartDate >= &start_range)
)) AND r.Type = 'BASIC';
```

Comment: Isit possible with sub query?

Comment: Sure, but a subquery will likely be less performant.  Any reason you prefer a subquery?  You can add the 'ArriveDate' and 'DepartDate' filters as a 'canned' query without using a subquery.

Comment: I find sub query difficult to understand, thereby really want to use this example to understand. Left Join I understand is simple.

Comment: You mean, you enjoy working harder for its own reward? ;)  The LEFT JOIN is the simplest way to find items that don't have matches in the range requested.

Comment: the above is also not a canned query. A canned query will have something like arrivedate = &arrivedate which prompts, as opposed to fixing a value.

Comment: So substitute '01-FEB-2013' and '24-FEB-2013' with parameter names - it doesn't affect the logic of the query.

Comment: ok thanks, I have been working on LEFT JOIN with other examples, so SUB QUERY is what I had in mind.

Comment: tried your example and get an error (missing expression) at line with IS NULL OR NOT IN

Comment: @MooHa: my bad, fixed now.

Comment: gave it real hard shot, but you condition is incorrect as rooms are available despite being booked. :(

Comment: it lists all rooms of type BASIC. it is not eliminating the booked room. ROOM 01 (BASIC TYPE) is booked from 10-mar-2013 to 15-mar-2013, and the range given is 14-mar-2013 to 20-mar-2013 yet it still lists room 01

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, which will detect conflicting bookings whether they are enclosing, enclosed by, or partly overlapping with the desired date range.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.* 
FROM Room r
LEFT JOIN BookingRoom br ON r.FloorNo = br.FloorNo AND r.RoomNo = br.RoomNo
LEFT JOIN Booking b ON br.BookingId = b.BookingId 
AND b.ArriveDate < &end_range AND b.DepartDate > &start_range 
WHERE b.BookingId IS NULL
AND r.Type = 'BASIC';
```

Comment: nope :( booked room still displays, see my way of inserting data into booking

Comment: @MooHa  For what dates (arrival, departure, and range)?

Comment: it lists all rooms of type BASIC. it is not eliminating the booked room. ROOM 01 (BASIC TYPE) is booked from 10-mar-2013 to 15-mar-2013, and the range given is 14-mar-2013 to 20-mar-2013 yet it still lists room 01

Comment: @MooHa  Then I think you have a problem with your field types/date comparisons.  Check this SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57a5b/1/0

Comment: very odd, but the issue was when I was inserting date, it was with TO_DATE('03-JUL-1980', 'DD-MON-YYYY') structure